# How to update credit card details on a Paypal subscription button

Tags: paypal

I have set up a subscription button,

When a user chooses to pay by credit card instead of a paypal account, how would they go about updating the credit card, eg. if it has expired.

I have seen a modify option , but that seems to be for upgrading their subscription to a different pricing rather than for updating credit card details.

If there a way to offer an option so they can update their credit card details attached to a subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Guest checkout" is not available with PayPal Standard Subscriptions or Express Checkout with Recurring Payments.  Any time they sign up that way they would have to create or login to a PayPal account, and then that's where they would update their card details.

If you're creating profiles directly on your site with credit card details and no redirection to PayPal then that means you must be using PayPal Payments Pro.  In that case you could update the profile details within your PayPal account or using the [UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/) API.  So you would have to build that tool into your site's user profile so they can update it accordingly.